# Doctrine2 Conditional Relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, relationship

My database schema:

```
LIKE      PAGE    ARTICLE    
id        id      id
userid    name    text
itemid
```

LIKE.itemid -> PAGE.id **"or"** ARTICLE.id

Normally, i use this way;

Page.php;

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Like", mappedBy="page")
 */
 protected $likes;
```

Article.php;

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Like", mappedBy="article")
 */
 protected $likes;
```

Like.php;

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="likes")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="itemid", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 protected $page;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="likes")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="itemid", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 protected $article;
```

But, But, itemid column will be the same in both tables (page and article). Will not be realized.

The question; I want to add a condition. Like this;

```
LIKE      PAGE    ARTICLE    
id        id      id
userid    name    text
itemid
**itemtype**
```

and

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="likes")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="itemid", referencedColumnName="id", **condition="itemtype=1"**)
 */
protected $article;
```

like this way, etc.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to create a supertype, say `Document`, from which `Article` and `Page` can inherit. Then your `Like`s can relate to `Document`s.

Doctrine2 ORM supports [three types of inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html): Mapped Superclass, Single Table, and Class Table. Picking the one you need will require some background on your usage requirements.

Read the Design-time considerations, Performance impact, and SQL Schema considerations of each option on the documentation page linked above to figure out which is right for you.

Comment: @user2993220 the entire section, [Inheritance mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html), that I linked is important. This is how you can model the kinds of class inheritance that you can do in PHP (e.g., an instance of the `Article` class is a `Document`, as is an instance of the `Page` class, and because `Document`s can be `Like`d, so can `Page`s and `Article`s) at the database level with Doctrine.